# "-bash: line 7: bc: command not found" error in script

Tags: command-line

I am having a script file for disk usage and I am getting the following errors:

```
$ DISKTOTAL=$(df -m |column -t |awk '{print $2}' |tail -n +2|awk '{Total=Total+$1} END{print Total}')
df: '/var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs/tracing': No such file or directory
$ DISKUSAGE=$(df -m |column -t |awk '{print $3}' |tail -n +2|awk '{Total=Total+$1} END{print Total}')
df: '/var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs/tracing': No such file or directory
$ DISKUSAGEPERCENT=$(echo "$DISKUSAGE / $DISKTOTAL * 100.0"|bc -l)
-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

It also gives this error while executing the script:

```
-bash: line 7: bc: command not found
```

Why is it not recognizing the `bc` command in my `DISKUSAGEPERCENT` command?

Comment: Maybe because it isn't installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Is this about Ubuntu, if so which version? `bc` is installed by default since I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `bc`:

```
sudo apt install bc
```

Comment: the user cannot install anything, is there any  other method possible?

Comment: No? For an application to work it has to be installed. That hopefully shouldn't be a surprise???

Comment: praveen.kumar@MUM:~$ sudo apt install bc
[sudo] password for praveen.kumar:
praveen.kumar is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
praveen.kumar@MUM:~$ apt install bc
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
praveen.kumar@MUM:~$

Comment: Ask the administrator to install the application.

Comment: let me check whether thats possible